# Sequence with two adherent points and no boundaries

Tags: calculus

This is the exercise given:

> Find a sequence with two different adherent points, which has no
>   boundaries. Write the subsequences of your sequence.

So the sequence I came up with was $(-1)^n$.
This will result in the sequence: $-1, 1, -1, 1,...$
So the two adherent points are -1 and 1, because adherent points are points on which the sequence returns a lot?

The subsequences would be $x_{n} :=$ 1 if n even, and -1 if n odd.
Is this correct? If not, what would be a better solution or example for this problem.

Could someone also explain a bit more about adherent points?

Definition adherent points from my cursus:
$x_{n} \rightarrow a \Leftrightarrow \exists\epsilon > 0 \forall N \exists n \geq N : |x_{n} - a| \geq \epsilon$

Comment: Do you mean *convergent* subsequences?

Comment: @MCT No, in the lesson we learned a term 'adherent points' it was similar to converging but 'weaker', that not all points in a given epsilon were inside the boundaries of the epsilo, but only some... I don't know the exact explanation because I also can't find anything on the internet about it.

Comment: (1). I think the $\geq$ in the last line should be $\leq.$  Then the RHS phrase  would say that for any $\epsilon >0$ there are infinitely many $n$ for which $|x_n-a|<\epsilon.$....(2). $x_n\to a$ is usually employed as an abbreviation for $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=a.$...(3). I have not heard of  the boundary of a sequence. What is it?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I doubt if they meant the only y-values in the sequence when you draw it on a graphic, or if they meant the limit.

Comment: @O'Niel I meant: you say "write the subsequences of your sequence." You probably want some condition on these subsequences, or else of course there are not just two subsequences.

Comment: @MCT Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: My guess about the def'n is that $a$ is a boundary point of a sequence  $S=(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ iff  $a$  is a limit point (adherent point) of $S$ but $\{n:x_n=a\}$ is finite. Is this what is meant?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, that's what's meant

Comment: Your example is correct. A different example is  $a_{3n-2}=1, a_{3n-1}=-1, a_{3n}=2n$ for $ n \in \Bbb N.$